# Is there a way to keep the side menu always open in Google Keep?

Tags: google-keep

I'd like to at least have the left sidebar menu open by default, as I use it a lot. Is there a way to not have to click the hamburger menu to open it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of 6/1/16, they updated the interface so that the side menu stays open. (Along with other improvements.)

Comment: which makes the question now "is there a way to make the side menu stay closed?"  It appears to have no setting to permit loading keep.google.com without the sidebar jumping up.

Comment: The Main Menu is closed again. Any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Clicking the hamburger menu icon in the top left (the three stacked vertical lines) toggles visibility of the side menu.

This also works in the new Gmail, Google Calendar, etc as well.

(I do wish Google would make discovering this feature more obvious.)